# how to fix link error in xcode4 (and ios5)

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, ios5, xcode4.2

I am using a 3rd party library and got the link error below in xcode4 with ios5. Can someone tell me how to fix this kinda error? Thanks a lot!!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      meatloaf::boundaries::boundaries(std::vector<meatloaf::scanline, std::allocator<meatloaf::scanline> >) in libScannerKit.a(boundaries.o)
      meatloaf::boundaries::find_boundaries() in libScannerKit.a(boundaries.o)
  "std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:
      meatloaf::boundaries::boundaries() in libScannerKit.a(boundaries.o)
```

Comment: Are you compiling in Obj-C++ mode? Or just Obj-C mode?

Comment: which 3rd party libraries? you may need to import some frameworks or include some paths in Header search paths/other linker flags

Comment: Does your lib have i386 code? or maybe just armv6/7 ? try with `lipo -info /path/to/your/lib`

Comment: @V1ru8, i guess the lib has i386 code for sure. where do i add  lipo -info /path/to/your/lib?

Comment: i think it's obj-c mode or both...

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, really appreciated! I finally found out i need to set "Other linker flags" as "-all_load -lstdc++" for both debug and release. In project setting's "Build Settings/Linking/Other Linker Flags"

Comment: @nanshi: could you please add your comment as an answer ? I had to click on "more comments" to find it out :)

Comment: just did, glad that it helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help, really appreciated! I finally found out i need to set "Other linker flags" as "-all_load -lstdc++" for both debug and release. In project setting's "Build Settings/Linking/Other Linker Flags"